# After renaming MySQL database, I can no longer access my Blog page

Tags: database, mysql

I renamed my database from WP_Alyona to WP_Aliona and now I cannot access my Blog page.

Here is what I get:

[image]

Here is what I did step by step:

1. Exported old database
2. Replaced all text from "Alyona" with "Aliona" in the exported sql file
3. Created new database named "WP_Aliona"
4. Imported the sql file that I edited and import was successful
5. Edited the WP-Config.php file and changed the line from "**define('DB_NAME', 'WP_Alyona');**" to "**define('DB_NAME', 'WP_Aliona');**"

I don't have any issues accessing the site or the WordPress dashboard at all.

I just have issues trying to access the Blog page as shown from the image above.

How do I go about correcting this?

Thank you all for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings > Permalinks and saving as is?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "saving as is"? I know went to Permalinks, but I couldn't see anything there I thought would resolve it.

Comment: Click on the save button without changing anything.